# constructor in c++/ visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to make a constructor in c++ with visual studio and I get this error :

> Error 1 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++
>   does not support default-int

I run a diferent code from my teacher that is almost the same and it work. I'm new in oop, so don't juge please.

An example:

```
class Stud {
char name[30];

const () {

this->cnp[0] = 'a';
this->cnp[1] = '/0';

}
};
```

Comment: const != constructor. You should use Stud () { } to create a constructor.

Comment: Where did you see constructors being written like that because that is not valid

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constructors are not written like that. Replace `const()` with `Stud()`.
The "name" must be the same as the name of the class.

`const` means something else — I'll leave you to look it up in your textbook!

Answer (score 10):

Well, `const` normally does not stand for "constructor", but if you try really hard...

```
#include <string>

class ructor
{
    std::string name;

    ructor() : name("a") {}

    static const ructor make() { return ructor(); }
};      // ^^^^^^^^^^^^ lol
```

Comment: Funny, but isn't going to help the OP is it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit In a way it can, if OP will analyse this snippet. Learning can be fun!

Comment: @BartoszKP: I don't think learning C++ is fun :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit :D Sorry, apparently now it is :P